# gpu::OpenCV and openMP

Tags: opencv, gpu, openmp

I try to use openMP to parallelise  a loop that contains gpu::openCV calls. Although I create an object inside the loop (so it is different for each thread) the results are not correct. They just become correct only if I enclose the gpu::openCV functions with a '#pragma omp critical' but in this way I have no speedup of the parallelisation, but overhead instead.

My question is why the concurrent execution of different instances of gpu::openCV calls with openMP gives wrong results?

Comment: Probably `gpu::openCV` uses a sort of shared global state, which makes it non-threadsafe.

Comment: How many GPUs does your system contain? If the answer is one, what makes you think that using multiple threads would improve performance (leaving aside the potential thread safety issues)?

Comment: @ Hristo, I also think that's the case, but is there a way to overcome it?   When I run multiple instances (via command line) the program works right, which probably means it is process-safe and not thread-safe.

Comment: @ talonmies, I have 1 Gpu but the profit would be from multiple cpu cores.